# Merge data frames that occupies the same position in two different lists

Tags: r

I have two big lists of data frames and need to merge the first data frame from dfList1 with the first data frame from the second dfList2 and so on. Is there a more elegant and perhaps efficient way to do this rather than loop throughout lists?

```
dfList1 <- list(df11, df12,..., df1N)
dfList2 <- list(df21, df22,..., df2N)
dfList3 <- list()
for (i in c(1:N){
    dfList3[[i]] <- merge(dfList1[[i]], dfList2[[i]], by=1)
}
```

The data frame structures from the two lists are different, which means I cannot use something like:

```
dfList3 <- lapply(names(dfList1), function(x) cbind(dfList1[[x]], dfList2[[x]])
```

P.S.: I couldn't be able to find any post covering this question. If you find something, please provide the link on comments.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `map2` from `purrr`.  you can accomplish the same functionality with base `mapply` but i think the `map2` syntax is a little more friendly.

using `map2`:

```
my_list  <- list(iris, iris)
my_list2 <- list(iris, iris)
out <- purrr::map2(my_list, my_list2, merge, by="Species")
```

using `mapply`:

```
out2 <- mapply(merge, my_list, my_list2, MoreArgs = list(by="Species"), SIMPLIFY = F)

identical(out,out2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Using purr for a couple of dfs the time goes from 0m0.435s to 0m0.427s. Not bad. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help.  if you are going with one of the solutions provided can you please accept it as the answer so we can close the question?

Comment: Questions are never closed unless they were unclear, off-topic, primarily-based, ...

Comment: pardon my misuse of "close"